# Explain the love triangle?

Tags: plot-explanation, duck-you-sucker

In Duck, You Sucker (aka A Fist Full of Dynamite), John (played by James Coburn) has numerous flashbacks to his IRA days.    In the final 15 minutes of the film, two seemingly important points are revealed:

> First, that he shot his friend who had been beaten and revealed his identity to the British military.

This seems clear to me plot-wise, as it's tied to the revelations about Villega.

I do not understand the second (final) flashback, where it is shown that

> the girl you see John with appears to be romantically involved with his friend as well when she stops kissing John and starts kissing his friend.

What is the meaning of this flashback?

Answer (score 1):

[According to this article](https://trailersfromhell.com/a-fistful-of-dynamite-duck-you-sucker/):

> All we are told about the past in Ireland is that revolutionary comrades Sean Nolan (David Warbeck) and John Mallory shared a ‘[***Jules & Jim***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_and_Jim)’-like relationship with the same girl, Coleen (Vivienne Chandler). In the crucial betrayal scene, **we see the Black & Tans bring the bloodied Sean into a bar, where he points out his buddy John for them**, like a Judas. Therefore, Sean is the ‘bad guy.’ **John’s slo-mo execution of his best friend is initially seen as tragic justice: informers must die.** John’s present disquiet comes from his memory of this violent act.
>
> But if the killing of Sean was justified, why is John so haunted by guilt? He’s certainly not a traitor to his cause. Why should the Kropotkin-reading idealist flounder all over Mexico, recklessly dynamiting soldiers in another country’s war?  John is not guilty, so why does he consider himself such a failure? Why does he so strongly identify with the weak Dr. Villega?
>
> The answer is in [***The Informer***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Informer_(1935_film)): John Mallory corresponds to Liam O’Flaherty’s tragic hero Gypo Nolan, who informs on his best friend Frankie Phillip for money. Leone’s flashbacks withhold key information from us, namely, how did the English capture Sean Nolan in the first place? In keeping with *The Informer*, I think **the hidden secret is that John informed on Sean. It wasn’t for money like Gypo Nolan, but because Sean stole his girl.**

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory, I'm trying to find anything to confirm it, but I think she represents the Irish Revolution.  It's the only way I can wrap my head around their full-on joy as the other enjoys intimacy.  It also fits that John would choose to envision his friend a true lover of the cause after Villega's death and just before his own.

I did find a reference to the scenes with her as a metaphor according to the DVD commentary by 'Noted Film Historian Sir Christopher Frayling'.  He made the same interpretation that she represents the revolution.